# OpenCV 2.4.5 read and display image crash

Tags: image, opencv, crash

Good morning all,

I am encountering a problem when attempting to run a simple program to open and display an image, the program will compile and run and create the "My Image" window, however the window is solid gray, and the program crashes with no error other then the standard windows "Test.exe has stopped working" shortly after opening the window.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.5 and Code::Blocks 12.11.  Also of importance is I cannot properly add the .dll's to the system variable "PATH" and as a result have pasted all of the .dll's to my project folder.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, the code giving me problems can be seen below.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
int main() {
        // read an image
        cv::Mat image= cv::imread("Jellyfish.jpg");
        // create image window named "My Image"
        cv::namedWindow("My Image");
        // show the image on window
        cv::imshow("My Image", image);
        // wait key for 5000 ms
        cv::waitKey(5000);
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: there are thousand similar questions in the web, how did you miss them??

Comment: +1 actually it took me a while to find a possible solution for this problem so it's not as straight forward as it seemes

Answer (score 0):

Maky sure that you have successfully read image:

```
...
// read an image
cv::Mat image= cv::imread("Jellyfish.jpg");
if (image.data == NULL)
{
     cerr << "image wasn't loaded! check path." << endl;
     return 1;
}
...
```

**Update:** just after 2 minutes of googling I found [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/172/segfault-in-opencv-242-and-mingw-on-winxp/) - this is bug and it's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That was a stupid mistake on my part.  I implemented the new bit of code to check if the image had been loaded, and achieved the same results.  I have also tried a variety of images and image types, all with no success.

Comment: No, I am fairly certain the path is correct, because if I enter an invalid path, say fish.jpg instead of jellyfish.jpg, image.data == NULL comes back true and the line "image wasn't loaded! check path." gets output.

Comment: A little further digging in the windows event viewer shows that the issue may be with one of my .dll's, indicated by this line:  _"Faulting module name: libstdc++-6.dll, version: 0.0.0.0"_ I am not sure how to go about addressing this issue, once again any help would be awesome!